# Angular 16 catch errors response from Django

Tags: django, error-handling, angular16

i learning Angular and i have a standard login service in Angular 16.2.0 and backend with Django. I post login details all working fine but when i catch errors i get only get only generic errors, Django is sending personalized messages for errors and i try to catch those to be able to show them in frontend.

This is my login service function:

```
    login(username: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
        return this.http.post(apiRoot + 'dj-rest-auth/login/',
            { username, password, },
        ).pipe(catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
            let errorMsg = '';
            if (error instanceof ErrorEvent) {

                errorMsg = `Error: ${error}`;
            } else {

                errorMsg = `Error Code: ${error},  Message: ${error.message}`;
                console.log(error.message)
            }

            return throwError(() => new Error(errorMsg));
        }));
    }
```

Now in case of an error this is all i got: Http failure response for https://link.stars-nexus.com/dj-rest-auth/login/: 400 OK  .

In network i have: [Network Headers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSkA2.png)

Django is sending personalized  error messages in response:

[Response Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW5zp.png)

That messages i try to catch them to be able to show them letter in front end. Django is taking care of all validations and provide proper personalized per error feedback. There is any way to catch them? Thank Kind regards.

To be able to catch those messages from error response to show them in frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a solution with Angular http client so i use for the request where i need nice feedback messages form Django: axios-observable from: [Axios Observables Doc](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-observable)

As an example you have: Login Service:

```
import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import Axios from 'axios-observable';

import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

import Axios from 'axios-observable';

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->

<!-- language: lang-js -->

    import { Injectable, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

    import Axios from 'axios-observable';



    const apiRoot = environment.apiUrl;
    @Injectable({
        providedIn: 'root'
    })
    export class LoginService implements OnInit {

        constructor() { }

        ngOnInit(): void {
        }

        // We will use Axios observable in the https requests that need a nice feedback for errors.
        // Documentation: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios-observable

        login(username: string, email: string, password: string): Observable<any> {
            let loginData
            if (username) {
                loginData = { username, password }
            } else if (email) {
                loginData = { email, password }
            } else {
                loginData = { username, email, password }
            }
            return Axios.post(apiRoot + 'dj-rest-auth/login/', loginData, { withCredentials: true });
        }
    }
```

The Login Component:

```
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth/auth.service';
    import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/auth/login.service';

    @Component({
        selector: 'app-login',
        templateUrl: './login.component.html',
        styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {

        form: any = {
            username: null,
            email: null,
            password: null
        };

        errorMessage: any = null


        constructor(private authService: AuthService, private loginService: LoginService) { }

        ngOnInit(): void {
            console.log(this.authService.isLoggedIn)
        }

        onSubmit() {
            const { username, email, password } = this.form;

            this.loginService.login(username, email, password).subscribe({
                next: (v) => { this.authService.saveUser(v.data.user);  },
                // Local storage variable is not affecting security as Django will check if user is really logged in or not.
                // We use this only to save some requests to server so if this local storage is false we will not ask the
                // server to check the status of user.
                error: (err) => { this.errorMessage = err.response.data; localStorage.removeItem('isLogetIn') },
            })

        }
    }
```

And in login html you can print nice error messages straight from server to user:

```
                    <div *ngIf="errorMessage">
                        {{errorMessage?.non_field_errors}}
                    </div>
```

non_field_errors will be replaced with the name of error that you want to print. Check in console / network what errors names are coming from Django.

See example: [Example error message displayed to user](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cZmxN.png)

I know this is not a permanent solution but until Angular will sort out the http client to give back nice error messages from Django this will do. Kind Regards, Ionut Zapototchi